# Deriving a consequence of continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Question:let A $\subseteq$ $\Re$ and let f: A $\to$ $\Re$ be continuous at a point c $\in$ A.Show that for any $\varepsilon$ $\gt$ 0 there exists a neighborhood $V_{δ}$(c) of c such that  $$x,y \in A \cap V_{δ}(c) \implies|f (x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$$

**Answer:**

Since $f$ is continuous at point $c$ ,given $\varepsilon$ $\gt$ 0 ,there exist δ$\gt$ 0  such that if any

$$x \in A |x-c|\ltδ \implies |f(x)-f(c)|\lt\varepsilon/2$$ Similarly for y anfd then get at the end $|f(y)-f(c)|$\lt$\varepsilon$/2.

Substract these two and get $|f (x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$.

Is this even possible?

Comment: I think you mean *add* the two and use the triangle inequality.  But it looks like the basic idea of your proof is correct.

Comment: @user46944 yes sorry that is what i meant .

Comment: Please use a more informative title.

Comment: @Qudit what should i do when the question can't fit into that space?

Comment: Surely you can come up with something more descriptive than what you have now. I'm not going to do it for you though.